# Git's .gitignore does not work with one or more asterisk qualifier +

Tags: git, gitignore

```
$ git version
git version 2.9.3.windows.1
```

I seem to be having trouble with the + (one or more) pattern matcher in .gitignore. Here is a test with `+` and `*`used as a pattern qualifier for digits embedded in the file name. I want to keep Test.txt in source control and ignore the Test[0-9]+.txt files.

Directory:

```
$ ll | grep Test
-rw-r--r-- 1 asdf 1049089      0 Apr  5 15:55 Test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 asdf 1049089      0 Apr  5 15:55 Test123.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 asdf 1049089      0 Apr  5 15:55 Test1235.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 asdf 1049089      0 Apr  5 15:55 Test124.txt
```

Git ignore file contents Test 1:

```
Test[0-9]+.txt
```

Test 1:

```
$ git status | grep Test
    Test.txt
    Test123.txt
    Test1235.txt
    Test124.txt
```

This should have filtered out the 2nd through 4th files.

Git ignore file contents Test 2:

```
Test[0-9]*.txt
```

Test 2:

```
$ git status | grep Test
    Test.txt
```

This should have filtered out ALL of the files.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .gitignore file is using globbing, *not* regular expressions. So using `+` is just not valid.

So your second attempt is actually closer to what you want.

```
Test*.txt
```

This would filter out files starting with `Test` and ending with `.txt` with anything in between. But it would also catch `Test.txt` itself because a `*` in glob can be zero-width.

What you have may be the simplest option.

```
Test[0-9]*.txt
```

That will match `Test` followed by any digit, followed by anything (including nothing), followed by `.txt`.

So it is imperfect, in that it will also match on

```
Test1foo.txt
```

Which has non-numeric text past the digit. But how specific your requirement is will dictate this. You can also just add a few patterns, like

```
Test[0-9].txt
Test[0-9][0-9].txt
Test[0-9][0-9][0-9].txt
Test[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt
Test[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt
```

If you really have to be sure it's all digits, then just pick how many digits, and use multiple entries like that to make it a very specific match.

Answer (score 2):

`.gitignore` only supports Glob patterns and not Regular Expressions.

This is what [gitignore man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) mentions:

> Otherwise, `git treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for consumption by fnmatch(3)` with the `FNM_PATHNAME` flag: wildcards in the pattern will not match a `/` in the pathname.
>   For example, "`Documentation/*.html`" matches "`Documentation/git.html`" but not "`Documentation/ppc/ppc.html`" or "`tools/perf/Documentation/perf.html`".

For more info search Glob Patterns vs Regex to see the differences.